# Need help cleaning up iterating through nested JSON

Tags: python-3.x

I'm iterating through JSON content.  I'm returning the sensor name + the temperature.  There are two `value` keys under `capability`.  I'm having trouble coming up with the simple logic to ignore the second one.  I'm fairly new to python but feel like this is a simple adjustment.  I just can't seem to find a good example on how to ignore the second value its pulling.

DATA:

```
  "remoteSensors": [
    {
      "id": "rs:100",
      "name": "Guest Bedroom",
      "type": "ecobee3_remote_sensor",
      "code": "TPCM",
      "inUse": false,
      "capability": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "type": "temperature",
          "value": "690"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "type": "occupancy",
          "value": "false"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "rs:101",
      "name": "Mudd Room",
      "type": "ecobee3_remote_sensor",
      "code": "X9YF",
      "inUse": false,
      "capability": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "type": "temperature",
          "value": "572"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "type": "occupancy",
          "value": "false"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "rs:102",
      "name": "Master Bedroom",
      "type": "ecobee3_remote_sensor",
      "code": "YDNZ",
      "inUse": false,
      "capability": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "type": "temperature",
          "value": "694"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "type": "occupancy",
          "value": "true"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "ei:0",
      "name": "Main Floor",
      "type": "thermostat",
      "inUse": true,
      "capability": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "type": "temperature",
          "value": "725"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "type": "humidity",
          "value": "37"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "type": "occupancy",
          "value": "false"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

CODE:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://api.ecobee.com/1/thermostat'
header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ZkEf7ONibogGpMQibem3SlhXhEOS99zK'}
params = {'json': ('{"selection":{"selectionType":"registered",'
                    '"includeRuntime":"true",'
                    '"includeSensors":"true",'
                    '"includeProgram":"true",'
                    '"includeEquipmentStatus":"true",'
                    '"includeEvents":"true",'
                    '"includeWeather":"true",'
                    '"includeSettings":"true"}}')}
request = requests.get(url, headers=header, params=params)
#print(request)
thermostats = request.json()['thermostatList']
remote_sensors = thermostats[0]['remoteSensors']


for eachsensor in thermostats[0]['remoteSensors']:
    for temp in eachsensor['capability']:
        name = eachsensor.get('name')
        temp = temp.get('value')
        print(name, temp)
```

Actual Results:

```
Guest Bedroom 690
Guest Bedroom false
Mudd Room 579
Mudd Room false
Master Bedroom 698
Master Bedroom false
Main Floor 731
Main Floor false
```

Expected Results:

```
Guest Bedroom 690
Mudd Room 579
Master Bedroom 698
Main Floor 731
```

Thanks for the help! @Naveen

Fixed:

```
for eachsensor in thermostats[0]['remoteSensors']:
    for temp in eachsensor['capability']:
        name = eachsensor.get('name')
        tempr = temp.get('value')
        id = temp.get('id')
        if id == '1':
            print(name, tempr, id)
```

Comment: You can just add a `if` condition at the end to ignore if the `temp = 'false'`.

Comment: duh!  You pointed me in the right direction.  I got the ID of each and looked for ID:1.  They're all ID:1 Thank you!

Comment: You can post your answer in the answer section and can mark your own answer to close this question.